# What is *&parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

I don't know much about C++ and I need to deal with a function at the moment. What does this mean in a function prototype?

```
void myFunc(int &size, signed char *&array);
```

Comment: `typedef` might make it easier to read: `typedef char* PCHAR;`, then it will become `PCHAR& array`

Comment: [so many duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%22*%26%22)

Comment: @LihO Using `typedef` here hides information that shouldn't be hidden (the fact that `array` is a reference to a pointer).

Comment: I'm sure there are duplicates, but it's so difficult to search for `*&`, nothing returns a result.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I think it depends on concrete situation, but I admit that defining an alias for `char*` isn't very lucky example. Although [someone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc230353.aspx) could argue about that :D

Comment: @BЈовић thanks for the tip, I just realized that there was a way to search for `*&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a reference to a pointer. So you don't pass a copy of the pointer to the function, instead you pass a **reference** to it, which means any changes to that value in the function would actually affect the original pointer you passed as argument.

Answer (score 2):

It means `array` is a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29) to a `signed char *`, i.e. to pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`*&` is a reference to a pointer

You suppose to call `myFunc` like this:

```
int size;
signed char *p;

myFunc(size, p);
```

Normally pass a reference to pointer to a function, so could change the pointer inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

think of it in this way:

```
(int) &size;
(char*) &array;
```

Comment: If you are down-voting, please comment the reason for downvote...